# Consolidar todas as colunas em apenas uma linha MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

Estou tentando fazer uma `query` que agrupe todos os resultado em uma só linha, ou seja, que não traga resultados duplicados. Já usei o `distinct` e o `group by`porém nenum dos dois me retornou o que preciso. 
A minha consulta é a seguinte:

```
SELECT TICKET, DATAHORA, TIPO, ESTADO, CRITICIDADE, LOGIN, PARECER, INFOPEND, PROP, DATAPROP, PREV, SRD, PROT, REAB, PRIENC
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TC.TN TICKET, TC.CREATE_TIME DATAHORA,  TT.NAME TIPO, TS.NAME ESTADO, TP.NAME CRITICIDADE, US.LOGIN LOGIN,
    CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%PARECER%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END PARECER,
    CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%INFORMACOESPENDENTES%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END INFOPEND,
    CASE  
        WHEN AR.A_SUBJECT LIKE  '%ATUALIZAÇÃO PROPRIETÁRIO%' THEN LEFT(AR.A_FROM, POSITION('<' IN (AR.A_FROM))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END PROP,
    CASE  
        WHEN AR.A_SUBJECT LIKE  '%ATUALIZAÇÃO PROPRIETÁRIO%' THEN (AR.CREATE_TIME)
        ELSE ''
        END DATAPROP,
    CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%PREVISAOATENDIMENTO%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END PREV,
    CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%SRD%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END SRD,
    CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%PROTOCOLO%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END PROT,
   CASE  
        WHEN TS.NAME LIKE  '%REABERTO' THEN (TS.NAME)
        ELSE ''
        END REAB,
   CASE 
        WHEN AR.A_SUBJECT LIKE 'FECHAR' THEN AR.CREATE_TIME
        ELSE ''
        END PRIENC

 FROM OTRS2.TICKET TC
 INNER JOIN OTRS2.TICKET_TYPE TT ON TC.TYPE_ID = TT.ID
 INNER JOIN OTRS2.TICKET_STATE TS ON TC.TICKET_STATE_ID = TS.ID
 INNER JOIN OTRS2.TICKET_PRIORITY TP ON TC.TICKET_PRIORITY_ID=TP.ID
 INNER JOIN OTRS2.USERS US ON TC.CREATE_BY=US.ID
 INNER JOIN OTRS2.TICKET_HISTORY TH ON TC.ID=TH.TICKET_ID 
 INNER JOIN OTRS2.ARTICLE AR ON TC.ID=AR.TICKET_ID
)A
```

Esta consulta está gerando o seguinte resultado:
[image: Resultado da query gerada]

Porém, eu preciso que o número de ticket não se repita, ou seja, que em uma linha ele agregue todas as colunas. 
Se eu usar o `group by ticket` acontece o seguinte:
[image: Resultado do group by]

Com, o `group by ticket`, ele retorna apenas uma linha, mas as informações das colunas (como por exemplo a coluna parecer) some!
Como posso colocar todas as informações em uma só linha?
Obrigada

Comment: se não tem nenhuma função de agregação, não vejo porque usar group by, acho melhor o distinct. após isso, teria que ver esse monte de case, pois me parece desnecessário... pra uma análise melhor, você tem que fornecer a estrutura das tabelas e alguns dados de amostra. Seria muito útil que colocasse no SQLFiddle

Comment: Se você quer agrupar como está na segunda figura, você precisa incluir todas as colunas para agrupar: `group by ticket, datahora, tipo, estado, criticidade, login,....` se alguma delas tiver diferença vai trazer mais de uma linha. Veja que "parecer" tem o valor vazio e "kkkkkk", isso vai gerar duas linhas, e assim por diante com as outras colunas

Comment: 1 Use um MAX nos CASEs <max( case .... end ...)> , 2 veja se o DATAHORA tem apenas a data e não data/hora.

Answer (score -1):

pelo q vi vc quer algo assim: onde uso um `alias` do banco como `d`, testado em `mysql`

```
`select d.TICKET AS TICKET,group_concat(d.PARACER separator ', ') AS PARECER from banco d group by d.PARECER`
```

terei uma saída assim:

+---+-----------------------------+
| TICKET |--PARECER-----+
+---+-----------------------------+
| 201822 | kkkkkk,kkkkkkkk |
+----+----------------------------+

adicione as outras colunas desejadas da mesma forma